# Design Patterns: evaluating security across multiple modules

Tags: spring, design-patterns, dependency-injection, spring-security

This question is more about design patterns, dependency injection than Spring Security itself, I expect folks without specific knowledge of Spring Security to understand this question.

In [Introduction to Spring Security 3/3.1](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Spring-Security-3) to verify whether the current user is authorized to do an action on a target object, Mike Wiesner implements a [`PermissionEvaluator`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-method-built-in). This bean is wired with the Security configuration and gets called on method annotations, before an action on a target object is carried on.

The purpose is to check whether an user is authorized or not to do a certain action on a specific object. He shows the following code (without null checks, for brevity, I suppose):

```
public class MyPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Object target, Object perm) {
        if (target instanceof MyRequest) { //first class of target object...
            MyRequest req = (MyRequest) target;
            if (perm.equals("cancel")) { //action we wish to perform on the object
                return auth.getName().equals(req.getEmployee());
            } else if (perm.equals("list")) { //another action
                return !hr.getEmployee().equals("rod") || auth.getName.equals("rod");
            }
        } else if (target instanceof ...) { //second class of target object...
            ...
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("hasPermission not supported");
    }

}
```

He mentions that this way of implementing, is only OK for small applications, but in practice, it should be split in multiple methods or classes. It was exactly what I was thinking:

- in a multi-module application, multiple modules can be unaware of one another
- we should apply the Open-Close principle (when adding a new module)

My question is, how would you address the problem?

My take would be to have a global permission evaluator and one permission evaluator for each target object class.

```
public interface TargetPermissionEvaluator extends PermissionEvaluator {
    Class getTargetClass(); //so we know for which target class we can use it
}

public class MyGlobalPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Autowired
    private List<TargetPermissionEvaluator> evaluators;

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Object target, Object perm) {
        for (MyEvaluator evaluator : evaluators) {
             if (target instanceof evaluator.getTargetClass()) {
                  return evaluator.hasPermission(auth, target, perm);
             }
        }
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("hasPermission not supported");
    }

}
```

The List of evaluators, will be defined in Spring XML configuration. What do you think? Is a good way or do you have better ideas? Am I missing some more suitable design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

First, there is an issue with using instanceof against Class.  You really want to use Class#isAssignableFrom in this instance (no pun intended).  However, that is not really central to your question.

To your original question, I really like the use of structures like Google Guava's [Predicate](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html).  It contains a single method likes(T), where T is a generic type, and returns a boolean.

Create a new interface such as

```
interface PollablePermissionEvaulator<T> extends PermissionEvaluator, Predicate<T> {}
```

Then, you can have your look query likes(T) on each, and if so, invoke a nested hasPermission() call.

Answer (score 0):

I think your proposed design is quite good and integrates well into Spring Security's design. After all, there are at least two other places where it is done like that:

- the default `AfterInvocationManager` delegates to `AfterInvocationProvider`s
- the default `AccessDecisionManager` delegates to `AccessDecisionVoter`s

In both cases, the interface of the delegated objects mirrors the interface of the delegator. Although it's easy to implement this makes me wonder why they didn't implement something like that for the `PermissionEvaluator` as well.